# remove submit from query parameter

Tags: symfony

I have a search form.  Problem is when I post it it creates a variable for the submit button

?search=key&submit=

I cant seem to figure out how to remove this and only show

?search=key

Any Ideas?  Thanks

```
private function createSearchForm()
{
    $builder = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder(null, 'form',null, array('csrf_protection'   => false))
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('trips'))
        ->setMethod('GET') 
        ->getForm() 
        ->add('search', 'text', array('required' => false, 'label' => false))
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
        ;
    return $builder;
}
```

Comment: I do not think that in one form, you can use two methods to submit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All form fields with `name` attribute are in query string. So easy way is just manually render submit in template and omit name.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be nicer to use POST for forms.

So I explain to you below how you can have the same functionality (including permalink to searchResult) with POST. The URLs **will even look nicer**: Instead of ?search=bla it will be /search/bla.

Route setup:

```
search:
    path: /search/
    defaults: { _controller: "AcmeDemoBundle:Search:searchRedirect" }
    requirements: { _method: POST }

search_result:
    path: /search/{search}
    defaults: { _controller: "AcmeDemoBundle:Search:search" }
    requirements: { _method: GET}
```

And then in `searchRedirectAction(Request $request)` just redirect to search_result

```
return $this->redirect(
    $this->generateUrl('search_result', array(
        'search'=>$request->get('search', '')
    ))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a little differently since I had a lot of forms that were going to need this functionality.

Symfony 3.x:

I created a form_theme that overrides 1 block

```
{# app/Resources/views/twig/form_themes/overrides.html.twig #}
{%- block button_attributes -%}
    id="{{ id }}" {% if type|default('button') != 'submit' %}name="{{ full_name }}"{% endif %}{% if disabled %} disabled="disabled"{% endif -%}
    {{ block('attributes') }}
{%- endblock button_attributes -%}
```

Then in my config:

```
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'
        - 'twig/form_themes/overrides.html.twig'
```

This will basically remove the name field from all submit type buttons, and therefor wont be included in your query params for `GET` requests.

** This may have some unintended side effects like not being able to run `->isClicked()` on a submit button. But for my case I dont need that.